# Are there any Minecraft username generators for available names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to buy Minecraft for my son and I've spent an hour typing in random letters and numbers and every single one is taken.

All over the internet I see people talking about how many people are registered for Minecraft as an excuse, but I don't have trouble on ANY popular site finding usernames, especially typing in random characters. It's impossible to believe every single username is taken on Minecraft but not on other popular sites.

So are there any generators out there that can make available names? My son has been asking for PC version since he got red-ringed on X-Box so I really don't want to let him down, but I've spent over an hour now and there are no names.

Comment: Do you really need help composing a string of random characters and/or words?

Comment: Try this website, I'm not sure if it pulls directly from the minecraft servers, but it could help. http://www.spinxo.com/minecraft-names

Comment: Strings of random characters worked pretty well for me.

Comment: This is Mojangs most basic "is-that-name-already-taken"-tool:
https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=Aiyion
Replace 'Aiyion' with the name of choice.
'True' means there is already someone who has got the name,
'False' is therefore what one wants to see ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Judging by the influx of "I'm having this problem too" answers, the problem is not with the usernames you're trying being taken, but with the website erroneously reporting it as such. Your best option at this point is to wait a day or so until Mojang fixes their system. You might try sending them an email, but they are likely already aware of the issue.

In the inexplicable case of you actually not being able to come up with an original username, try entering random characters or using a dictionary and avoiding "cool" words like "shadow", "dark", "demon", "stalker", "ghost", etc.

Comment: I was thinking their js validation on the names was buggy, but trying to turn js off to test they won't load their site. I'll try again today to see if this was the case. I did send them an email as well. I think this was the case because, while I first tried names I wanted, I ended up trying things like "tugiofhg75674" and it ALWAYS reported the name was taken.